# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.Decimal)' method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I had the first Query and change to the second because I needed to add two more informations. Now I getting this error bellow, and don't have idea how to fix it. =(

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.Decimal)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Is there any way to make this query with `Where` before `Join`? Like it was written in the `First Query`?
If yes, how can I do that?

**First Query**

```
    public virtual List<ReturnType> MethodName(Control control)
    {
        var db = GetDbConnection();

        var numericdate = DateTimeHelper.ToInt(control.ActivityDate);

        return db.TB_TABLE_1
                    .Where(x => x.DATA_MOVIMENTO == numericdate &&
                                x.NR_TENTATIVA == control.AttemptsNumber &&
                                x.CD_LEGADO == control.LegacyCode)
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(x => new ReturnType
                    {
                        ActivityDate = DateTimeHelper.ToDate(x.DATA_MOVIMENTO),
                        AttemptsNumber = x.NR_TENTATIVA,
                        LegacyCode = x.CD_LEGADO,
                        BlockadeProtocol = x.PRTCL_BLQ,
                        BlockadeSequence = x.SQ_BLQ,
                        ValueOfBlockade = x.VLR_A_BLOQUEAR,
                        OriginCode = x.CD_PROCEDENCIA,
                    }).ToList();
    }
```

**Second Query**

```
    public virtual List<ReturnType> MethodName(Control control)
    {
        var db = GetDbConnection();

        var numericdate = control.ActivityDate;

        return db.TB_TABLE_1
                .Join(db.TB_TABLE_2,
                        tb_1 => new { protocolo = tb_1, sequencial = tb_1.SQ_BLQ },
                        tb_2 => new { protocolo = tb_2.PRTCL_BLQ_VLR, sequencial = tb_2.SQ_BLQ_VLR },
                        (tb_1, tb_2) => new { tb_1, tb_2 })
                .Join(db.TB_TABLE_3,
                        tb => tb.tb_2.VARAJUIZO,
                        tb_3 => tb_3.VARAJUIZO,
                        (tb, tb_3) => new ReturnType
                        {
                            ActivityDate = Convert.ToDateTime(tb.tb_1.DATA_MOVIMENTO),
                            AttemptsNumber = tb.tb_1.NR_TENTATIVA,
                            LegacyCode = tb.tb_1.CD_LEGADO,
                            BlockadeProtocol = tb.tb_1.PRTCL_BLQ,
                            BlockadeSequence = tb.tb_1.SQ_BLQ,
                            OriginCode = tb.tb_1.CD_PROCEDENCIA,
                            Court = tb_3.TRIBUNAL,
                            CourtStick = tb_3.NM_VARAJUIZO
                        }
                )
                .Where(x => x.ActivityDate == numericdate &&
                        x.AttemptsNumber == control.AttemptsNumber &&
                        x.LegacyCode == control.LegacyCode)
                .ToList();
    }
```

**Control.class**

```
 public class Control
{
    public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; }

    public decimal AttemptsNumber { get; set; }

    public string LegacyCode { get; set; }
```

}

**ReturnType.class**

```
public class CourtOrderRequest
{
    public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; }

    public decimal AttemptsNumber { get; set; }

    public string LegacyCode { get; set; }

    public string BlockadeProtocol { get; set; }

    public string BlockadeSequence { get; set; }

    public string OriginCode { get; set; }

    public string Court { get; set; }

    public string CourtStick { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's likely due to the fact that there is no SQL equivalent to `Convert.ToDateTime` (or it's not defined in the LINQ syntax).  In your first query you calculate that after the query has executed (forced by the `ToList`) causing it to be calculated in C#, not SQL.

Comment: @MikeH Thanks for the answer!
So to fix this error I need to find a SQL syntax to do this conversion?

Comment: You'll need to take a step back and consider what you're trying to do with that call to Convert.ToDateTime(). Is `DATA_MOVIMENTO` a string that's intended to represent a date? Why isn't that field encoded as a DateTime/datetime2 or DateTimeOffset in the database in the first place?

Comment: You can try to do the conversion in SQL or you could just do the conversion after the result is returned, just like you did in the first query.